# Copy into running fine but not loading data gzip file

Tags: talend, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using talend bulk execution to load data from s3 to snowflake. Talend tFileArchive converts the file to gzip format , file.csv.gz and upload it to s3 bucket. Copy into which gets executed through talend bulk component looks like below. It does nt throw an error or something but does nt load data either. If I try to load csv file without zip , it works fine.

```
File: file.csv.gz

Copy into table
    from 's3://bucket/'
    credentials=(aws_key_id='' aws_secret_key='')
    FILE_FORMAT=(type=csv compression=gzip field_delimeter=',' skip_header=1 field_optionally_enclosed_by='\"' empty_field_as_null=true)
    force=true
```

Can someone point wheres the issue ? Even if I execute above command through snowflake UI  , it says ran successfully but does not load. File has data.

Thank you

Comment: What do you see when you run a VALIDATE() function against that table?  Do you see error records?  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/validate.html

Comment: It does not error out , if I keep csv file to same s3 bucket location, it picks up csv file with out an issue and loads it , it also picks csv.gz file but does bt load data , row_parsed =0 shows there,

Comment: It doesn't need to error in order for the validate() function to be used.  If you run it, what do you see in return?

Comment: Also, what is likely happening is that the COPY INTO statement isn't finding the files in the bucket.  So, it succeeds with 0 files processed.  If that is the case, you may have a permissions issue to the bucket.  Try setting up a stage in Snowflake to that location with credentials, and then running a LIST command to see if its "seeing" the files.

Comment: Thank you for your response, It was configuration issue at talend side , While gzipping the file , it was creating 0 byte file hence was causing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

View your table's COPY history to see if an error was thrown or not.  Then try and LIST the file in your S3 bucket to make sure your STAGE is working.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(information_schema.copy_history(table_name=>'YourDatabase.YourSchema.YourTable'
                                           , start_time=> dateadd(days, -1, current_timestamp())));   

LIST @YourStage
OR
LIST 's3://bucket/'
```

Also make sure you are executing your COPY INTO statement under a role that has permission to see the s3 bucket and write to the destination table.